# Do JTextAreas have a "default" KeyListener to show the character when a key pressed? (consume() avoiding chars to be displayed)

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, keyevent

I have 2 JTextAreas called "taOriginal" and "taTranslated", if the user does not press a given button ("tglbtnEnableLetters"), the only thing that can be written on these TextAreas are digits, but if the user presses the button, everything can be written. In order to do this I have this code:

```
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if(!tglbtnEnableLetters.isSelected()) {
            char key=arg0.getKeyChar();
            if (!Character.isDigit(key) && !Character.isWhitespace(key)) {
                arg0.consume();
            }
        }
    }
```

That code works as intended, but I don´t understand how does consume() exactly work, my first assumption was whether if the TextAreas had a keyTyped event and making a custom one replaces the default behaviour, but since a given component can have several  listeners of the same type I don´t think this assumption is correct, so how does consume affect to the TextArea?

Comment: Short answer, use one or more `DocumentFilter`s

Comment: *"but I don´t understand how does consume() "* - `consume` is "meant" to stop listeners who might be notified after you from performing operations - in my experience, it's unreliable and you should use different functionality to solve this problem, such as a `DocumentFilter`.  Also remember, there are plenty of other ways text can be added to a text component other then the keyboard